# BigCommerce Stencil Start Uncaught Error: Module parse failed

Tags: npm, webpack, bigcommerce

I'm getting the following error after running stencil start and accessing the localhost url in my browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| var getAccount = function getAccount() {
>   return import('./theme/account');
| };
| 
    at Object../assets/js/app.js (bootstrap:83)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
(index):1064 Uncaught TypeError: window.stencilBootstrap is not a function
    at (index):1064
```

This just started happening this morning, I was able to run stencil yesterday without any problems.

I've followed the steps here exactly:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/getting-started/installing-stencil

I've tried uninstalling stencil and reinstalling multiple times. I've also tried using a fresh clone of cornerstone multiple times in multiple different directories. I can't get rid of this error and have tried all of the troubleshooting suggestions from the docs. There are no errors in the terminal.

I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Node Version: v.6.4.0

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue on our end with the Cornerstone 3.1 release, which can be downloaded through GitHub but hasn't rolled out to production yet. We've got an engineering ticket in to address it, but in the meantime, you can roll back to the [Cornerstone 3.0](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/releases/tag/3.0.0) release to bypass the error. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Hey there, just wanted to let you know a fix was merged for this. PR linked here: https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/pull/1428 Thanks again for reporting this!